# Spring - how to handle exception

Tags: spring, velocity

I am using Spring with Velocity. At times velocity produces an exception like

> Error in interpolating string literal : org.apache.velocity.exception.MethodInvocationException: Invocation of method 'getMessage' in  class org.springframework.web.servlet.support.RequestContext threw exception class org.springframework.context.NoSuchMessageException : No message found under code 'XX' for locale 'en_US'.

Question is - can I instruct spring to suppress `NoSuchMessageException` ? I am pretty new to Spring so do not know if I can create a exception handler which will not throw a exception if the message is not found? In my use case, it is a valid use case of not finding some of the messages in the `messages.properties` file.

[EDIT] - I found a way `org.apache.velocity.app.event.MethodExceptionEventHandler` to supply an even handler to velocity. I am however not sure how to register it with Spring.

Answer (score 2):

It would be better, I think, to address the problem directly, rather than trying to suppress the exception, which could lead to avoid behaviour and uncompleted operations.

However, you didn't tell us how you'd want the system to respond in cases where the message is not defined for a given code. Do you want a blank String, or should the code itself be used as the default message?

I'm assuming that somewhere in your Spring context you have a defined a `messageSource` bean of some sort. These `MessageSource` beans usually have a property `useCodeAsDefaultMessage`. This defaults to `false`, but when set to `true` they will return the code itself as the message, in cases where no message is defined.

Alternatively, you can subclass the `MessageSource` class (whichever one you're using), and override the `getDefaultMessage()` method to handle cases where the code cannot be resolved.